# How to get other properties (not textContent) using Pyppeteer?

Tags: python, node.js, puppeteer, pyppeteer

For example, in the following HTML:

```
<img src="some_url" class="my_image">
```

How do I use Pyppeteer to get the value of src? I've seen examples of this in Puppeteer, but not sure how to do it in Pyppeteer. Simply doing the following doesn't work:

```
selector = await page.waitForSelector("my_image")
source = await selector.getProperty("src")
```

Answer (score 1):

`evaluate` method can be handy here, as this provides large capabilities of JavaScript.

so for example, if HTML is following

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<title>  pyppeteer test </title>
</head>
<body>
    
    <img src="https://simpleappdesigner.pythonanywhere.com/" class="my_image">
</body>
</html>
```

then the following code will extract the src or any property which needs to be extracted. **Note:** Comments added along with code

```
import asyncio
from pyppeteer import launch

async def main():
    browser = await launch({'headless':False}) # made as false as helps when devloping the script
    page = await browser.newPage()
    await page.goto('file:///Users/xxx/Development/stackoverflow/my_page.html') # navigate to the url, in my case navigating to file
    img_element=await page.J('[class=my_image]') # search by query selector which is equivalent to CSS selector in java script
    img_element_src=await page.evaluate('(img_ele) => img_ele.getAttribute("src")', img_element) # feed the element and evaluate will execute the JS function
    print(f"image src : {img_element_src}")
await browser.close()

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())
```

**result**:
image src : https://simpleappdesigner.pythonanywhere.com/